# Apex Trigger/Class add Contact field value to Task

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, class, tasks

Whenever a task is created on a contact, I would like to populate that task with the value of a number field from that contact. Is a Trigger/Class the best way to do this, or are there simpler methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Trigger and it depends on your comfort, you can also do this using javascript button. Since you need to populate a value from the contact to the Task to complete this using a workflows but that may have some restrictions.